# Swift Generics function with escaping closure

Tags: ios, swift, generics, closures

I have method:

```
func getUsers(completion: @escaping (_ users: [User]?,_ error: String?)->()) { router.request(.getUsers) { (data, response, error) in
 var users = [User]()
 users = try JSONDecoder().decode(Array<User>.self, from: responseData)
}
```

But i want to do this function more generic. **I tried** :

```
    func getUsers<T: Decodable>(completion: @escaping (_ users: [T]?,_ error: String?)->()) { router.request(.getUsers) { (data, response, error) in 
      var users = [T]()
      users = try JSONDecoder().decode(Array<T>.self, from: responseData)
      completion(users, nil)
}
```

But when i call this func users array from escaping closure is [_]. If i just use only T users array is [User.Type] and it does not conform to Decodable so i can do `JSONDecoder().decode`. How should it look ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Array< User > is not convertible to '[_]?'

This is because of  **_ users: [T]?** type  ***Optional***

Your method is working fine you just have to define optional array.

```
 self.getUsers{ (res:Array<User>?, error) in

 }
```

I have created one similar

```
 func getUsers<T: Decodable>(completion: @escaping (_ users: [T]?,_ error: String?)->()) {

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "test")!) { (data, res, error) in
            guard let resData = data else  {completion(nil,"data is nil"); return}
            do {
                var users = [T]()
                users = try JSONDecoder().decode(Array<T>.self, from:resData)
                completion(users, nil)

            } catch {
                completion(nil, error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

And call it

```
     self.getUsers{ (res:Array<User>?, error) in

    }
```

Here is struct

```
struct User :Codable {
    var name:String?
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your answer but still i have error:
Cannot convert value of type (Array<User>?,_) -> () to expected type ([_]?, String?) -> ()'

Comment: @hds For me it is working with same let me post the code try to copy it and check

Comment: Okey, I will try

Comment: @hds Try to copy paste everything and just compile

Comment: I got it ! Thanks

Comment: but i have still this issue if i pass next generic parameter into this function

Comment: @hds Didn't get you what do you mean next generic parameter, it has only one generic parameters

Answer (score 0):

Hey Hds you have done most of the work correctly, only one missing point that is knowledge about how Decodables work.

An array of Decodable is also Decodable. So what I'm trying to say is you don't need to explicitly mention that you want to decode `Array<T>.self`, you can put T.self as long as you have passed to the function that you are expecting an `Array<T>.self` so T => `Array<T>`

So in your case when you call this function and pass `[User]` as the generic parameter, `T` will be `Array<User>.self` while decoding. So here is what the code should look like. I'm not sure if the code will 100% compile because I have some missing components, but it gets the idea across.

```
func get<T:Deocdable>(completion: @escaping (_ object: T?,_ error: String?) -> ()) {
    router.request(.getUsers) { (data, response, error) in
        do {
            let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: responseData)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Decoding failed because: ", error.localizedDescription)
        }
}
```

Also I added the do catch block because the `try JSONDecoder()` throws.

Also to add on how you should call the method its like the following:

```
get { (users: [User]?, error) in

}
```

Hope this helps.